# Show alert at intermediate values ​​(Objective-C or any other)

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem, and I tried several ways, but I can not find the solution.

The problem (e.g in Objective-C)
I have a progress that starts in 0 and for each iteration the value increases 3 points. ie 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, etc

Well, I need that when the counter exceeds 10, an alert is displayed, but only when more than 10, 20, 30, 40, etc. In the intermediate values ​​(3, 6, 9, etc) should not be displayed.

For example:

```
0 -> nothing
3 -> nothing
6 -> nothing
9 -> nothing
12 -> ALERT!!
15 -> nothing
18 -> nothing
21 -> ALERT!!
24 -> nothing
27 -> nothing
30 -> ALERT!!
33 -> nothing
36 -> nothing
[...]
```

Any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round `value` down to a multiple of 10.  Round `value-3` down to a multiple of 10.  If the rounded values differ, show the alert.

```
static int roundToMultipleOf10(int n) {
    return 10 * (n / 10);
}

static void showAlertIfAppropriateForValue(int value) {
    if (roundToMultipleOf10(value) != roundToMultipleOf10(value - 3)) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `roundToMultipleOf10(n - 3)`. Should `n` be `value`?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement means that `ALERT!!` only appears for x0, x1, or x2 where x is some 10s digit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
    if (i > 10 && i % 10 <= 2) {
        NSLog(@"ALERT!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution after doing a medley of all your answers. 
Thank you!

```
    // Round function
    int (^roundIntegerTo10)(int) =
    ^(int value) {
        return value / 10 * 10;
    };

    // Progress evaluator
    if (_currentProgress > _nextProgress && _currentProgress >= 10) {
        NSLog(@"ALERT!!!");
        _nextProgress = roundIntegerTo10(_currentProgress) + 10;
    }
```